# Is it possible to get MSBuild property by string name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to retrieve an MSBuild property (`$(Something)`) by using the string value `"Something"` stored in another property. I tried to use MSBuild's Escape/Unescape methods but it still just prints `$(Something)` and not the property I want:

```
  <Target Name="OutputBuildMacro">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyToGet>MSBuildProjectFile</PropertyToGet>
      <MacroName>$([MSBuild]::Escape('$'))($(PropertyToGet))</MacroName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="$([MSBuild]::Unescape('$(MacroName)'))" />
  </Target>
```

Output when I run `msbuild TestProject.vcxproj -t:OutputBuildMacro`

```
Project "D:\TestProject\TestProject.vcxproj" on node 1 (OutputBuildMacro target(s)).
OutputBuildMacro:
  $(MSBuildProjectFile)
Done Building Project "D:\TestProject\TestProject.vcxproj" (OutputBuildMacro target(s
)).
```

I also tried to wrap the unescaped value with another pair of `$(` and `)`, but that just gives me an error. Is it possible to retrieve msbuild property using a string value rather than literal name written in XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try it:

```
  <Target Name="OutputBuildMacro">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyToGet>MSBuildProjectFile</PropertyToGet>
      <MacroName>$(PropertyToGet)</MacroName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="$(MacroName)" />
  </Target>
```

**>Is it possible to retrieve msbuild property using a string value rather than literal name written in XML?**

As far as I know, it is impossible. The literal name is unique, but the string value isn't.